# WebSql disabled by default in IOS13, a workaround exists for Safari, but can it apply to PWA's?

Tags: ios, safari, progressive-web-apps, ios13, web-sql

iOS13 appears to drop support by default for WebSQL. There exists a workaround to enable WebSQL in Safari, but this appears to only apply for Safari. I haven't found such a workaround for Firefox or Chrome on Safari.

Similarly, this workaround does not appear to apply for a PWA launched from the homescreen. Is there a workaround specifically for PWA's?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be, busy writing an iOS app to add the webSQL/SQLite functionality into a WKWebView.  Even with WebSQL enabled safari closes the connection, it would remain open "forever" in ver 12 and below.

Comment: @Adam Marshall we are looking into replacing our implementation with IndexedDB

Comment: wish that was an option for us, did you look at the google library: https://github.com/google/lovefield if you think in SQL like we do it might be a good solution